why does Flask-Elasticsearch timeout duration differ between docker pause and docker run?
Can you help me figure out why I experience this weird behavior that Flask waits the set Elasticsearch timeout in one condition but not in the other?
docker-compose.yml defines a Flask service and an Elasticsearch service. I can use depend_on: ... service_healthy to start both successfully with docker compose up. But I read that it is better practice to let the services themselves rather than docker handle retry, timeouts, and the like why I tried that instead of depends_on.
The app.py script implied by the Flask Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT flask run includes
from es.client import Search
es = Search()

The es.py script includes
class Search:
    def __init__(self):
        self.es = Elasticsearch(..., timeout=10, max_retries=12, retry_on_timeout=True)

After docker compose up the flask service does indeed retry 12 times. But the timeout is not the duration of 10 seconds in fact way, way less. That said, some timeout is expected because Elasticsearch takes more time than Flask to be completely up and running. I can start the Flask service again successfully.
Yet, running docker pause Elasticsearch (and I fail to manually connect to it) and docker start Flask; Flask will now retry for the 10 seconds duration and with 12 retries. I can docker unpause Elasticsearch within the max retries limit and Flask immediately connects successfully.
See output below and notice that the errors are different: ProtocolError vs. ReadTimeoutError. Though the WARNING messages similarly state that x seconds (from 2-30 through the retries) are put on timeout.
I don't understand the reason for this behavior. Do you have any suggestions? Is the difference reflecting less Flask's actual ability to 'respect' Elasticsearch timeout durations than the difference is reflecting an artifact of pause (I dunno e.g. that pause changes how connections are attempted such that it differs from connecting to a stopped or not fully started service)?
# timeout duration > 0.01s
INFO:elastic_transport.transport:GET http://host.docker.internal:9200/ [status:N/A duration:0.004s]
WARNING:elastic_transport.node_pool:Node <Urllib3HttpNode(http://host.docker.internal:9200)> has failed for 10 times in a row, putting on 30 second timeout
WARNING:elastic_transport.transport:Retrying request after failure (attempt 9 of 12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/elastic_transport/_transport.py", line 342, in perform_request
    resp = node.perform_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/elastic_transport/_node/_http_urllib3.py", line 202, in perform_request
    raise err from None
elastic_transport.ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))



# timeout duration ~ 10s
INFO:elastic_transport.transport:GET http://host.docker.internal:9200/ [status:N/A duration:10.015s]
WARNING:elastic_transport.node_pool:Node <Urllib3HttpNode(http://host.docker.internal:9200)> has failed for 2 times in a row, putting on 2 second timeout
WARNING:elastic_transport.transport:Retrying request after failure (attempt 1 of 12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/elastic_transport/_transport.py", line 342, in perform_request
    resp = node.perform_request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/elastic_transport/_node/_http_urllib3.py", line 202, in perform_request
    raise err from None
elastic_transport.ConnectionTimeout: Connection timeout caused by: ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='host.docker.internal', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))

update:
class Search:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.es = Elasticsearch('http://host.docker.internal:9200')
            
        retries=0
        max_retries=12
        
        while retries < max_retries:
            try:
                
                client_info = self.es.info()
                logging.info("Connected to Elasticsearch!")
                logging.info(json.dumps(client_info.body, indent = 4))
                break

            except Exception as e:
                time.sleep(10)
                retries += 1
                logging.info(f"Waiting {retries}/{max_retries} 10 more seconds for Elasticsearch...")
                if retries == max_retries:
                    raise e


You need a delay between retries, which is different from a timeout.  I don't obviously see a setting for that in the Elasticsearch documentation.  (Not particularly Docker-specific, which is a reason to recommend this approach.)

Thank you @DavidMaze. I also tried including wait_for_it in the entrypoint before flask run. This did not have the desired effect as the connection was quickly establish despite elasticsearch not being fully loaded so to speak. Thus far, docker's depend_on is the easiest working solution despite it not working at the application level as some suggest is best practice. Do you have an opinion about that?

If you're only worried about this working in a Compose setup, Docker health checks might be easier to set up.  The path you're pursuing will also work without containers or in Kubernetes, I definitely agree it's "better".

@DavidMaze I tried to add a delay (if I understood you correctly), see update. This however did not work in the sense that the Flask container terminated quickly and with the error messages similar to what I already posted.

okay, adding time.sleep(10) before calling ES the first time actually worked; not because a successful connection was immediately made, but at least it tried another time 10s later. Can't explain why. Thank you though. If you understand why this happens please feel free to answer in brief.
